# backup mysql database by php on other drive (windows)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, backup, dump

I'm using Laravel and I'm looking for a way to back up my database with php code. I want these backup files to be saved in paths such as other drives or usb drives (by the user's choice: so that the user enters the Windows path in the software, such as: "D: \").

I also use xampp to set up a server on Windows.

It is better to suggest if you know the standard Laravel package in this regard.

Comment: have you tried this https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup

Comment: very good! thank you so much @djunehor

Comment: only one question! My software runs on Windows. I want to tell the user to enter their desired paths in the system (for example, in drive D or folder in that drive) How can I define this path in the  `config/filesystem.php`? I mean the path section. How to define an out-of-project path in Laravel?

Comment: I believe you can specify the full path. If the user has permission to access the path, it'll work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup. it's very good and has many options to manage your backup.

I suggest if you want to show a better report of the backups that have been taken to your user in the software. Create a table and store additional information in it and use this table to display information to the user.